# Detect ajax submit

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I need to run a specific javascript function only when the page is submitted using ajax.
I've tried the following:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(Page, Page.GetType(), 
    "scriptName", "MyFunction();");
```

But it seems to run during normal post-backs as well. I've also tried replacing the `Page` object with the `UpdatePanel` control but without any difference.

Is it perhaps possible inside the javascript function `MyFunction()` to detect if it is an ajax or normal submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solved the problem. Thanks to @user1341446 for pointing me in the right direction.

Register the javascript function on submit:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(Page, Page.GetType(), 
    "scriptName", "MyFunction();");
```

Inside the function detect if ajax submit:

```
function MyFunction()
{
  var isAjaxSubmit = false;
  if (typeof (Sys) != "undefined")
    isAjaxSubmit = 
       Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._postBackSettings.async;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize Sys.WebForm.PageRequestManager two events

1) add_initializeRequest --> When an ajax post back is initiated

2) add_endRequest --> when an ajax post back is finished.

PageRequestManager also provides a function "get_isInAsyncPostBack()" which tells that if page is still in process of an existing ajax postback.

Example:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(function () {

 var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

 // Only one async request at a time
 if (prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {
 prm.abortPostBack();
 }

 //Call the function or process you want to perform on ajax request begin
 });

 Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () {
  //Call the fucntion or process you want to perform on ajax request end
 });
```

Any question, feel free to ask

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I check `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack()` inside `MyFunction()` it always returns false. (even on ajax submits)